# Can I turn on the hotspot in objective-c in IOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, tethering

Can I turn on the **`hotspot`** in **`objective-c`** in **`iOS 7`**?

I've searched StackOverflow, and some information I've found has said **"objective-c does not support turning on the `personal hotspot`".** But this information was from a few years ago.

Does **`objective-c`** support turning on the **`hotspot`** in **`iOS 7`** now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enable such System settings via any app (at least without a jailbreak).
**Objective-c** results in an app for an iOS-device, thus you cannot achieve this.

Apple does not allow any app which tries to enter the App Store to activate:

- WiFi
- Location services
- Personal hotspot
- Many more features not named above

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I turn on the `hotspot` by `Setting UI` , can I get the information for the client which connected to this `hotspot` ?

Comment: You should go to SO for this, if you want to achieve this via code.

Comment: Sorry...I am new for this. What is the SO ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com